# Ruby On Rails Routing Error (was previously working)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

So I'm working on a project and I want to create new subcategory. The link was working but I'm not getting the following error:

> No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"subcategories"}

The project is fairly new so my routes file is very simple:

```
Mrprice::Application.routes.draw do

get "admin/index" => 'admin#index'

 resources :products
 resources :subcategories
 resources :categories

 root to: 'store#index', as: 'root'

end
```

In my view:

```
<%= link_to 'New Subcategory', new_subcategory_path %>
```

I'm sure there's a typo somewhere or else the solution is very simple but I can't for the life of me figure it out.
I hope I've given enough information and that someone here knows what the problem is!

edit: subcategories_controller.rb (relevant methods)

```
def show
@subcategory = Subcategory.find(params[:id])

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @subcategory }
end
end

def new
@subcategory = Subcategory.new

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # new.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @subcategory }
end
end

  def create
@subcategory = Subcategory.new(params[:subcategory])

respond_to do |format|
  if @subcategory.save
    format.html { redirect_to @subcategory, notice: 'Subcategory was successfully      created.' }
    format.json { render json: @subcategory, status: :created, location: @subcategory }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @subcategory.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

rake routes gives:

```
     admin_index GET    /admin/index(.:format)            admin#index
    products GET    /products(.:format)               products#index
             POST   /products(.:format)               products#create
 new_product GET    /products/new(.:format)           products#new
edit_product GET    /products/:id/edit(.:format)      products#edit
     product GET    /products/:id(.:format)           products#show
             PUT    /products/:id(.:format)           products#update
             DELETE /products/:id(.:format)           products#destroy
subcategories GET    /subcategories(.:format)          subcategories#index
                 POST   /subcategories(.:format)          subcategories#creat
 new_subcategory GET    /subcategories/new(.:format)      subcategories#new
edit_subcategory GET    /subcategories/:id/edit(.:format) subcategories#edit
     subcategory GET    /subcategories/:id(.:format)      subcategories#show
                 PUT    /subcategories/:id(.:format)      subcategories#updat
                 DELETE /subcategories/:id(.:format)      subcategories#destr
      categories GET    /categories(.:format)             categories#index
                 POST   /categories(.:format)             categories#create
    new_category GET    /categories/new(.:format)         categories#new
   edit_category GET    /categories/:id/edit(.:format)    categories#edit
        category GET    /categories/:id(.:format)         categories#show
                 PUT    /categories/:id(.:format)         categories#update
                 DELETE /categories/:id(.:format)         categories#destroy
            root        /                                 store#index
```

note: not sure how to fix the formatting - I already tried a code block

Comment: you have an issue with the show path, you lack an id somewhere

Comment: Show the contents of the file that the error points to.

Comment: I really don't understand why the show path is throwing an error when I'm trying to create a new subcategory. Nowhere in my view am I calling on show. Also there aren't any ids because the project is new and I haven't created any subcategories yet.

Comment: @Marek Lipka The error is not pointing to any file. It's just a routing error and tells me to run rake routes

Comment: @SomeName show the contents of your controller then. I think it can be caused by wrong `redirect_to` call.

Comment: Have you got a show method in your subcategory controller ?

Comment: @MarekLipka I've edited the question to show the controller methods as well

Comment: @SomeName what did you change comparing to working version?

Comment: @MarekLipka Absolutely nothing. I was working on a different part of the project and I compared my code to a working model - basically the categories model - and I seriously don't see any differences

Comment: What's the output of `rake routes`?

Comment: @nTraum - I've added the output from rake routes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I finally figured it out!

The problem was a routing error on the new subcategory form.
I had:

```
<%= link_to "Subcategories Home", subcategories_index_path %>
```

I know this was incorrect so I changed it to:

```
<%= link_to "Subcategories Home", subcategories_url %>
```

Mostly I just went through [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) with a fine toothed comb until I figured out the correct way to route back to subcategories#index.